# Question closed and deleted a little fast?

Tags: support, status-declined, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm not sure why [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200603/nesting-if-condition) (10k) got closed and deleted so fast. Although it is certainly not the best question ever it looked okay-ish, **improvable**, and certainly not worth a deletion.

I suggest it got reopened.

Comment: And what is your question/request?

Comment: The deleted question is unclear. Very unclear.

Comment: It is not well written but I think it is clear: how can I improve `if(a && b && c) {} else if (a && b && d)` and the answer is `if (a && b) { if (c) {} else if (d) {}}`...

Comment: I would understand a closure as too localized maybe...

Comment: I agree, this question should not have been deleted so soon after it was closed (4 minutes), especially not with the +2 comment asking why the question got closed having no responses. Nobody learns from `Close + Instant-Delete`. But they do learn from `Close, Explain, Delete Later`, or from `Close, Explain, Edit, Reopen`. I would vote to undelete, but I can't since a moderator deleted it, so instead I've flagged it with a note saying it's been edited, and please undelete. The community can decide if it's worth reopening or not.

Comment: @Rachel You don't have all the facts...  You should probably wait a little before the righteous indignation kicks in =)

Comment: @casperOne Shhh my "righteous indignation" is on vacation and I don't want to wake it up yet this year. Your answer provides the missing bit of information that explains why it was deleted so fast though, thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree that a question that's not obviously bogus (spam or whatever) should not be closed within a minute of posting, with no opportunity for the user to update/clarify it first.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The question was deleted at the request of the user who posted the question.

Considering that there were no answers, and therefore no rep loss for anyone else, we obliged that request.

Comment: That explains it all indeed!

Comment: Given that 10k+ users can still see deleted questions, perhaps the mod commenting with "deleted by request" prior to deletion would have avoided the confusion/indignation/etc.

Comment: @PeterBoughton Perhaps, but frankly, that's too much of a time sink for moderators.  If I had to put a comment on everything I've deleted (even by request)...  Forget it, I'd get nothing done.  It's easier to simply address things on meta if people *really* want to know for the specific questions that people want to inquire about, like this one.

Comment: If implemented as a generic mod-specific close/delete reason it wouldn't take any extra time (it's just be a different option to select).

Comment: @PeterBoughton Don't disagree, if it was there, we'd use it, but that's a specific feature request for the devs to hash out.  We'd have to get the data behind how many times this is asked for and then get *deletion reasons*, which might be a whole separate issue.